Migration from Next.js 13 to Next.js 15 & React 18 - Error occurred prerendering page "/page"
We migrated our app from Next.js 13 to Next.js 15 and this repo is inside our mono repo, and we are using server side rendering for one of our page for the first time
the dev server works fine but when we do a build, it's giving us the pre-rendering error
note: we are using React 18 for now because React 19 was just released and we want to wait for a few months for it to mature
this is the _app folder
import '@repo/i18n';

import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

import type { EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { MotionLazyContainer } from '@/components/animate';
import createEmotionCache from '../utils/createEmotionCache';
import ThemeProvider from '@/theme';
import { useDispatch, useSelector, wrapper } from '@/redux/store';
import ThemeLocalization from '@/locales';
import SnackbarProvider from '@/components/snackbar';
import { SettingsProvider, ThemeSettings } from '@/components/settings';
import Progress from '@/components/progress';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { addYears } from 'date-fns';
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4';
import appVariables from '@/utils/config-global';
import { handleLoadLeedFeaderScript, removeScript } from '@/utils/functions';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { deleteCookie, setCookie } from 'cookies-next/client';
import { handleCookiePreferencesModal } from '@/redux/slices/homepage';
import CookiePreferencesModal from '@/components/cookie-banner/cookie-preferences-modal';
import CookieBanner from '@/components/cookie-banner';

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode;
};

interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
}

function MyApp(props: MyAppProps) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment -- disabling for now
  const { Component, pageProps, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache } = props;
  const { store, props: wrapperProps } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(pageProps);

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <meta content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport" />
      </Head>

      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <SettingsProvider>
          <MotionLazyContainer>
            <ThemeProvider>
              <ThemeSettings>
                <ThemeLocalization>
                  <SnackbarProvider>
                    

                    <Progress />

                    {getLayout(<Component {...wrapperProps} />)}
                  </SnackbarProvider>
                </ThemeLocalization>
              </ThemeSettings>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </MotionLazyContainer>
        </SettingsProvider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

When I do a build I'm getting this error in the terminal
[Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.]
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:493)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:476)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at bd (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error occurred prerendering page "/signup". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:493)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:476)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at bd (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error occurred prerendering page "/brands/[brandname]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:493)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:476)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at bd (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error occurred prerendering page "/entertainment". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:493)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:476)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at bd (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
nd-web-home:export:dev: Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:493)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:476)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at bd (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at $c (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Zc (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
nd-web-home:export:dev:     at Z (F:\work\nd-web-mono\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
nd-web-home:export:dev: Export encountered an error on /login, exiting the build.
nd-web-home:export:dev:  ⨯ Static worker exited with code: 1 and signal: null
nd-web-home:export:dev: error Command failed with exit code 1.
nd-web-home:export:dev: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
nd-web-home:export:dev: ERROR: command finished with error: command (F:\work\nd-web-mono\apps\nd-web-home-next.js) C:\Users\Rohil\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1735300529076-0.5797800575893091\yarn.cmd run export:dev exited (1)
nd-web-home#export:dev: command (F:\work\nd-web-mono\apps\nd-web-home-next.js) C:\Users\Rohil\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1735300529076-0.5797800575893091\yarn.cmd run export:dev exited (1)

 Tasks:    0 successful, 1 total
Cached:    0 cached, 1 total
  Time:    1m37.703s
Failed:    nd-web-home#export:dev

 ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)

The build command is this - env-cmd -f .env.development next build
one of the pages in the pages directory & the code
/stories.tsx
import { useEffect, type ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Container, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';
import HomepageLayout from '@/layouts/homepage-layout';
import MasonryGrid from '@/sections/stories/masonry-grid';
import { useSettingsContext } from '@/components/settings';

Stories.getLayout = (page: ReactElement) => <HomepageLayout pageTitle="">{page}</HomepageLayout>;

function Stories() {
  const { handleSetThemeMode, onChangeColorPresets } = useSettingsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    onChangeColorPresets('ndOrange');
    handleSetThemeMode('light');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo title="NameDrop - Stories" />
      <Container>
        <Typography variant={'h4'} fontWeight={'800'} textAlign={'center'} mt={10} mb={5}>
          Stories
        </Typography>
        <MasonryGrid />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default Stories;


package.json
{
  "name": "----",
  "author": "----",
  "email": "----",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "export:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development next build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@calcom/embed-react": "^1.5.0",
    "@cloudflare/next-on-pages": "^1.13.5",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
    "@iconify/react": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.135",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "15.1.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@repo/eslint-config": "*",
    "@repo/i18n": "*",
    "@repo/ui": "*",
    "@repo/utils": "*",
    "@types/node": "20.4.1",
    "@types/numeral": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.15",
    "@types/react": "18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "@types/react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.3",
    "@types/wavesurfer.js": "^6.0.6",
    "@wavesurfer/react": "^1.0.7",
    "cookies-next": "^5.0.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.11.17",
    "i18next": "^23.2.8",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.11.5",
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "next": "15.1.2",
    "next-image-export-optimizer": "^1.12.3",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "8.0.0",
    "next-seo": "^6.6.0",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.16",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-card-flip": "^1.2.3",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.3.5",
    "react-ga4": "^2.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.2",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.4",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.10.3",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.2.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
    "react-typed": "^2.0.12",
    "react-use-audio-player": "^1.2.6",
    "react-waypoint": "^10.3.0",
    "simplebar-react": "^3.2.6",
    "stylis": "^4.3.2",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^7.8.8",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/stylis": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "ts-migrate": "^0.1.35"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.18.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.1"
  }
}


We are using turbo-repo and have the same versions of Next.js everywhere

That error 130 says you're trying to render an object as a component somewhere.

@AKX i'm trying to figure out where but i'm unable to find it.. also i tried to only fix the stories page and removed everything and just returned a fragment with text & then tried to build it. it is still the same
